# Submitting form resubmits the same data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, datatables

I'm having some problems with a table that I created using a [Gyrocode](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) example. I modified it to fetch and submit data via ajax and to leverage [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) server side processing.

Basically what is happening is I can select row1 and submit the form and everything works fine. I then de-select row1 and select row2 and when I submit, it will submit for row1 & row2.

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLzmjeo9/) to replicate and am logging the form variable to the console.

**Step1**: Selected row1 and clicked 'Request Selected' button, here is the output

```
<form id="frm-example">
    <div class="table-responsive">...</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1">
</form>
```

**Step2**: Did not refresh page, de-selected row1, selected row2 and clicked 'Request Selected' button, here is the output. You can see the first row is still in the variable.

```
<form id="frm-example">
    <div class="table-responsive">...</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="2">
</form>
```

I tried clearing the form variable when a request was successfully posted but it seems to come back. I'm not sure how to deselect everything and reset the variables back to null when a request was already submitted.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form id="frm-example">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                  <button id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-success" disabled><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Request Selected (0)</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="display select table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        <input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox">
                      </th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Position</th>
                      <th>Office</th>
                      <th>Extn.</th>
                      <th>Start date</th>
                      <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                </table>
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
//
// Updates "Select all" control in a data table
//
function updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table) {
    var $table = table.table().node();
    var $chkbox_all = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]', $table);
    var $chkbox_checked = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked', $table);
    var chkbox_select_all = $('thead input[name="select_all"]', $table).get(0);


    // If none of the checkboxes are checked
    if ($chkbox_checked.length === 0) {
        chkbox_select_all.checked = false;
        if ('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all) {
            chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
        }

        // If all of the checkboxes are checked
    } else if ($chkbox_checked.length === $chkbox_all.length) {
        chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
        if ('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all) {
            chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
        }

        // If some of the checkboxes are checked
    } else {
        chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
        if ('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all) {
            chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = true;
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Array holding selected row IDs
    var rows_selected = [];
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'sAjaxSource': 'data.php',
        'columnDefs': [{
            'targets': 0,
            'searchable': false,
            'orderable': false,
            'width': '1%',
            'className': 'dt-body-center',
            'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<input type="checkbox">';
            }
        }],
        'order': [
            [1, 'asc']
        ],
        'rowCallback': function(row, data, dataIndex) {
            // Get row ID
            var rowId = data[0];

            // If row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
            if ($.inArray(rowId, rows_selected) !== -1) {
                $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
                $(row).addClass('selected');
            }
        }

    });

    setInterval(function test() {

        table.ajax.reload(null, false); // user paging is not reset on reload
        $(".dataTables_processing").hide();
    }, 2000);


    // Handle click on checkbox
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

        // Get row data
        var data = table.row($row).data();

        // Get row ID
        var rowId = data[0];

        // Determine whether row ID is in the list of selected row IDs 
        var index = $.inArray(rowId, rows_selected);

        // If checkbox is checked and row ID is not in list of selected row IDs
        if (this.checked && index === -1) {
            rows_selected.push(rowId);

            // Otherwise, if checkbox is not checked and row ID is in list of selected row IDs
        } else if (!this.checked && index !== -1) {
            rows_selected.splice(index, 1);
        }


        if (this.checked) {
            $row.addClass('selected');
            document.getElementById("btn-submit").innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>' + " Request Selected (" + rows_selected.length + ")";
        } else {
            $row.removeClass('selected');
            document.getElementById("btn-submit").innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>' + " Request Selected (" + rows_selected.length + ")";
        }

        // Update state of "Select all" control
        updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table);

        $('#btn-submit').prop('disabled', (!rows_selected.length));

        // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Handle click on table cells with checkboxes
    $('#example').on('click', 'tbody td, thead th:first-child', function(e) {
        $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
    });

    // Handle click on "Select all" control
    $('thead input[name="select_all"]', table.table().container()).on('click', function(e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#example tbody input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('click');
        } else {
            $('#example tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked').trigger('click');
        }

        // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Handle table draw event
    table.on('draw', function() {
        // Update state of "Select all" control
        updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table);
    });

    // Handle form submission event 

    $('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "process.php";
            var form = this;

            // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
            $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId) {
                // Create a hidden element 
                $(form).append(
                    $('<input>')
                    .attr('type', 'hidden')
                    .attr('name', 'id[]')
                    .val(rowId)
                );
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(form);

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: Why don't you make a much smaller demo of what is going on? In doing so you may well find the problem yourself.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I'll try but all the JS is needed for the selection to function in the datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out! I ended up iterating back over the selected rows and removing the elements from the form variable after I get a success back from ajax.

```
   $('#frm-example').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "process.php";
            form = this;

                  // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
                  $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){
                     // Create a hidden element 
                     $(form).append(
                         $('<input>')
                            .attr('type', 'hidden')
                            .attr('name', 'id[]')
                            .val(rowId)
                     );
                  });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                     $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){
                     // Remove hidden element 
                     $(form).children("input").remove();
                  });

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
```